# Breaking CSV File into multiple files based on a column including Total Sum of the columns

Tags: python, file, csv, python-itertools

I found a solution here on stackoverflow https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31081953/split-csv-file-into-two-csv-files-based-on-the-content-of-a-column for breaking a file into multiple columns which is as follows

```
import csv
from itertools import groupby

for key, rows in groupby(csv.reader(open("newone.csv")),
                         lambda row: row[0]):
    with open("%s.csv" % key, "w") as output:
        for row in rows:
            output.write(",".join(row) + "\n")
```

This does the job fine but i want to print out the sum of numbers in certain columns as well like 3rd and 4th column, how do i do that?
check out this image - https://i.stack.imgur.com/pFTbY.jpg
this code works fine but i need to generate the last line highlighted in orange as well in that image(i added those there manually). how can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

This would add the number at the end of each line:

```
for row in rows:
    output.write(",".join(row))
    sum_of_certain_cols = row[2] + row[3]
    output.write("," + sum_of_certain_cols + "\n")
```

If you want to put the sum in some position, you should do an `insert` like:

```
    sum_of_certain_cols = row[2] + row[3]
    row.insert(4, str(sum_of_certain_cols))
    output.write(",".join(row) + "\n")
```

**Edit after comments**

1. Don't forget to cast the column to the data type, although I think this line is not longer needed as I understood your needs:

   ```
   sum_of_certain_cols = int(row[2]) + int(row[3])
   ```
2. If you want the total addition at the end you'll need an accumulator, e.g.:

   ```
   sums = [0] * len(rows)
   ```

   Then inside the loop do all the sums:

   ```
   sums[1] += int(row[1])
   sums[2] += int(row[2])
   ```

   And then after the loop write them all:

   ```
   output.write(",".join(sum) + "\n")
   ```

Comment: thanks @xbello but it didn't work, it just adds a number to the row on the right and it looks like its concatenating rather than adding. 


the code i shared above works well(please check this image: http://i.imgur.com/KIxLOnr.jpg) but it doesn't give the last line highlighted in orange in the image - ie the sum of the columns A and C(i added that part manually there). How can i get the sum of those two rows as well ?

thanks.

Comment: thanks for the quick response. I am really a novice so just wanted to make sure: is this the correct full code then? http://pastebin.com/M4mXsZEb

thanks again.

Comment: You should remove the line 7, and you have to add as many dict keys as columns you have in your CSV (if you have 3 columns, `sums = {"row_1": 0, "row_2": 0, "row_3": 0}` and so on). Remember `iteritems()` in the last line!

Comment: @B A, by this time you should have noticed that the final row is unordered. I have updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: i tried but couldn't get it to work? If you don't mind, could you please update the answer with the full code along with your edits? :) thanks.